# PDO errorCode doesn't work with prepare

Tags: php, pdo, prepare

```
$sql = "dSELECT * FROM users";
$dbQuery = $this->dbal->query($sql);
$dbError = $this->dbal->errorInfo();
```

$dbError gets the syntax error information.

If the same is used for prepared statement it doesn't return any error after prepare.

This code is from php.net

```
<?php
/* Provoke an error -- bogus SQL syntax */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('bogus sql');
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

ErrorInfo doesn't work in this way.
I use

```
$dbQuery = $this->dbal->prequery($sql);
$dbError = $dbQuery->errorInfo(); // $this->dbal->errorInfo(); doesn't work, too.
```

Comment: did you try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263443/pdo-connection-test/6263868#6263868)?

Comment: Tried that, but non of this worked.Actually the silent mode is by default and it works with the dbal->query.

Comment: When I use:

$this->dbal->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

var_dump(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE); everytime returns 3.SILENT, Warning or Exception it returns 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [manual](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) says:

> If the database server successfully
>   prepares the statement, PDO::prepare()
>   returns a PDOStatement object. If the
>   database server cannot successfully
>   prepare the statement, PDO::prepare()
>   returns FALSE or emits PDOException
>   (depending on error handling).

That means that you don't have an object when it fails: you have a boolean `FALSE`.

Try changing the [PDO error handling](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.