# PDO execute statement hangs

Tags: php, oracle, apache, pdo

I have a problem when calling execute on a prepared statement using PDO.

Here is my code:

```
        $db = Connection::getConnection();

        $query = 'INSERT INTO stories (st_title, st_authors, st_content, st_cover) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';

        $params = ['title', 'Authors', 'content', 'cover'];

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

        echo "before <br>";
        $stmt->execute($params);
        echo "after <br>";
```

If I comment out the line *$stmt->execute($params);*, both "before" and "after" show up. However, if I leave it uncommented, neither of them show up.

I have also tried using *bindParam()* instead of executing with an array, but I got the same result.
It's also worth taking note that inserting into the database, with the exact same parameters, from sqlPlus works flawlessly.

I am running an oracle 11g database server locally.

Any help would be highly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while now.

**Edit:** I mentioned it in the title, but forgot to mention it here too. When this code runs, the server hangs indefinetely and I am forced to restart apache.

**Edit2:** The connection is ok, and I figured out the source of the problem.
On the stories table, i have an unique constraint on st_title.
The problem occurs when i try to insert a story with the same title as a previous one AFTER that previous one has been DELETED.
If I remove the unique constraint, the problem goes away.

However I would like to keep that constraint. Any ideas as to what could cause this?

**Edit3:** The triggers I have on the stories table:

```
--auto-increment on st_id--
DROP SEQUENCE stories_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE stories_id_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stories_id_auto_inc
BEFORE INSERT ON stories 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT stories_id_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.st_id
  FROM   dual;
END;
/

--auto-completion for st_date_added--
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stories_date_added
BEFORE INSERT ON stories 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT sysdate
  INTO   :new.st_date_added
  FROM   dual;
END;
/ 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stories_delete
BEFORE DELETE
   ON stories
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM st_cat
    WHERE st_id = :old.st_id;

    -- DELETE FROM characters
    -- WHERE st_id = :old.st_id;

    DELETE FROM favourites
    WHERE st_id = :old.st_id;

    DELETE FROM bookmarks
    WHERE st_id = :old.st_id;

    DELETE FROM comments
    WHERE st_id = :old.st_id;

    DELETE FROM ratings
    WHERE st_id = :old.st_id;
END;
/
```

The last one is the only relevant one, I think, but i posted them all, just in case.

It's worth noting that the problem only occurs with PDO. If i do the same operations from sqlplus, it works fine.

**SOLVED:** As it turns out, it wasn't a problem with my code, it was simply the fact that I didn't do a commit; in sqlplus after deleting the rows, and PDO dis weird things with them. (It didn't just show me the normal  "title is already taken" message, which is what fooled me).

Comment: Are you 100% your $db connection works?
( http://stackoverflow.com/a/6263868/1063823 )

Comment: Try [errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) on different stages and come back with the results. Also read [Oracle error monitoring](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/monitoring001.htm)

Comment: "before and after [...] neither of them show up" - see also http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php Show your PHP/Webserver's error log files.

Comment: Are there any triggers? Unclosed transactions? Explicit locks?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Database Connection is not setup correctly.

Take a look at this post to check if your connection is stable and you can succesful perform queries to it.

[PDO Connection Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263443/pdo-connection-test/6263868#6263868)